# Is there a difference in the following c++ input methods?

Tags: c++, input, char

In c++, there are several ways of taking input. What is the difference between the two following cases?

```
char x;
x=cin.get();
/* The above code can be a one-liner */
```

vs

```
char x;
cin.get(x);
```

Comment: Reference on both: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: One passes a non-const reference to x, the other can be used to initialize a constant variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case they're the same (in terms of behavior of `get` and the character extracted from the stream). From [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/):

#### std::istream::get

```
int get();
istream& get (char& c);
```

*"Extracts a single character from the stream.
The character is either returned (first signature), or set as the value of its argument (second signature)."*

Comment: For his purposes they are giving the same results, but the second example is returning the `this` pointer of the ifstream accessed by cin.  He is simply ignoring it.

Comment: The 2nd get has the added benefit being able to test the state of the stream at the same time as calling get. ie. `while (stream.get(ch)) {`

Answer (score 1):

There basically is no difference between these two cases

cin.get(void) returns a char from the input stream

cin.get(char &c) returns void but sets the passed variable to a char read from the input stream

If you are really picky about memory, cin.get(char &c) will maybe save you 1 allocation for a char being a return type, however I would prefer use the one-liner char x = cin.get();